# SharePoint 2013 List Checkbox validation

Tags: validation

I've created a list with Test Check Box column contains two check box choices choice 1, choice 2. 
When user's click choice 1 or choice 2 or both and click save a pop-up needs to show up how do i achieve this with validation settings formula on my list.

[image: check boxes]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use js in the validation, it is not so advanced. In order to achieve that you need to embed custom javascript inside of the form new or edit aspx itself.

Answer (score 2):

Validation isn't done with Javascript, but rather with SharePoint's own validation syntax. What validation does is check if the form is *valid* according to your rules. It doesn't create popups, but rather a block of red text explaining that something in the form is not correct.

If you want to create a popup, you'll need to add the Javascript into either the NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx views with a script editor web part. You can access the views via the ribbon. Below's the points of access for a list library and document library respectively.

[image]

[image]

From there you can add a Script Editor WebPart, and add your Javascript.